# Retornar lista em um array - WebApi C#

Tags: c#, array, lista

Boa galera.
Estou precisando retornar uma lista de cursos vinculado a um determinado aluno, essa lista será consumida através do get de uma WebApi.

tenho as classes "aluno", "curso" e "cursoAluno" (tabelas na base - EntityFramework).

a tabela aluno não tem o id do curso, a tabela curso não tem o id do aluno, daí que criei a cursoAluno, nela eu tenho o Id(identity), idAluno, idCurso.

necessito que ao consumir o webApi seja retornada a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
"id": 2,
"nome": "João Silva",
"endereco": "RUA que sobe e desce",
"mensalidade": 0,
"cursos": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "Portugês"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "nome": "Matemática",
    }
]
},
```

alterei a classe aluno para :

```
public class Aluno {
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Nome  { get; set; }
public string Endereco  { get; set; }
public double Mensalidade  { get; set; }
public List<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}
```

e no momento de popular a lista fiz assim:

```
var aluno = dbContext.Alunos
    .Include("Cursos")//Irá carregar os cursos vinculados aos alunos
    .Find(id);//Obtém apenas um aluno
```

Mas não é retornado da maneira que eu preciso.
Alguém pode me ajudar nessa ?
Estou usando WebApi C#

Grato.

Comment: Mas não é retornado da maneira que eu preciso. Alguém pode me ajudar nessa ? Estou usando WebApi C# ...... esta retornando o que?

Comment: Bom.. o seu model está certo com o Json informado.
dá uma olhada aqui :
http://json2csharp.com/

Ele vai gerar o model correspondente pro seu Json ai e tá certinho.. provavelmente sua chamada ai tem algo errado.. cole aqui COMO tá vindo errado! abs.

Comment: Mostra a classe curso também. Você está usando Entity Framework correto?